# How do I get related data in PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

In my **PostgreSQL** database I have table with such structure:

```
| organization_id | organization_name | parent_organization_id | tree_organization_id |
|-----------------|-------------------|------------------------|----------------------|
| 1               | Alphabet          |                        |                      |
| 2               | Google            | 1                      | \1\2                 |
| 3               | Google X          | 2                      | \1\2\3               |
```

As you can see, the table stores a hierarchical relationship between organizations. Let's say as input I have an array of ids. For simplicity, let's say I have the following array `[3]`. How do I get a list of all parent organizations from an array? In my case, the final result which I want to see is this:

```
| organization_id | organization_name | parent_organization_id | tree_organization_id |
|-----------------|-------------------|------------------------|----------------------|
| 1               | Alphabet          |                        |                      |
| 2               | Google            | 1                      | \1\2                 |
```

Do I need to focus on the `tree_organization_id` column or recursively iterate over the `parent_organization_id` column?

**PostgreSQL version:**

```
PostgreSQL 11.4 (Debian 11.4-1.pgdg90+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516, 64-bit
```

**Columns types:**

```
| Column name            | Column type |
|------------------------|-------------|
| organization_id        | int8        |
| organization_name      | varchar     |
| parent_organization_id | int8        |
| tree_organization_id   | varchar     |
```

Comment: What are the types of your columns? What do you expect as output if the input array is longer? And most importantly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I updated my post with information about columns types. The max length of the input array can be 2000. The min length of the input array can be 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Common Table Expression(CTE)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to list all the parent or children relationship. With the help of CTE, you can eliminate the tree_organization_id column.

The [link](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-recursive-queries-in-postgres) provides a very good tutorial for CTE beginners.

Answer (score 0):

it's either way you can follow, i would prefer to recursively iterate over `parent_organisation_id`.

here is the Query Below.

```
select * from company where
    organization_id in( select parent_organization_id
                       from company where parent_organization_id is not null);
```

you can find the 
[working example from here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e340e/9/0)

Comment: Thank you for your replay but your code is not applicable if there is more data in the table and I want to know all the parents of certain organizations. I assume that in the subquery you need to apply the array I mentioned in my post. Do you have any other ideas?